# Setting submit form button with a background image?

Tags: html, css

i'm simply trying to set a background image to my submit button in my form. I've tried a couple variations of methods but every time I get the default browser button. Anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

**HTML**

```
<div id="headerSearch">
    <form method="post" action="Test.php">
        <div id="headerSearchBar">
            <input class="tbSearch" type="text" name="search" size="12" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
        <div id="headerSearchBtn">
            <input class="btnSearch" id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#headerSearch{
    float:right;    
    width:80%;
    height:80px;
}
#headerSearchBar{
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    height:80px;

}
.tbSearch{
    height:25px;
    width:95%;
    margin-top:27.5px;
    margin-left:2%;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:0
}
#headerSearchBtn{
    float:right;
    width:10%;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
.btnSearch{
    background-image:url(../IMAGES/btnSearch.svg) no-repeat;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top:27.5px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904817/adding-an-image-to-submit-button-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a method that fixes the issue, as Michael St Clair has mentioned I needed to use just `background` in the css rather than `background-image`. This removed the default browser image and didn't display my selected image.

I used a different method that has now fixed the issue, I tried this method before but with the `background-image` tag rather than with just `background` as Michael St Clair suggested, which all and all has now fixed the issue.

**HTML**

```
<input class="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" name="btnSearch" type="submit" value="">
```

**CSS**

```
.btnSearch{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top:27.5px;
}

input#btnSearch{
    background:url(../IMAGES/btnSearch.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just `background`

```
background:url(../IMAGES/btnSearch.svg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this has definitely done something as the default image has disappeared, however there is now no image there at all just a blue border. Any ideas?

Comment: Try an absolute url, to make sure that you have the right path. So put the domain name in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-size:100% 100%` to your button css. Something like this: http://codepen.io/shreya1289/pen/QEKGWa