# How can I make the button in pure css?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Anyone can help me with the best solution to make the button in pure css as well as the font and font style?

[image: Button]

Comment: well. what have you tried ? share html css code

Comment: Looks pretty simple to create that one. Have you tried at all? (*Edit:* The guy who upvoted this question, I don't know what you were thinking.)

Comment: It's not a button. It's a checkbox. I would start by using a checkbox and a label and apply some styling to it. Looks like you might be able to do it with just those elements.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "Get my programming done for free" website. Its a website for programming help. Please share your code and we will try to help.

Comment: Please, share your code.

Comment: @Harry I have similar thoughts quite often ... There are lots of amazing upvotes

Comment: True @vals and a very sad state :(

Comment: @Nevermore requiem. :(

Comment: @LataBelle Requiem happened on OP's question. :D

Comment: Thank you to all who responded. Just new with stack overflow.

Below is my code:

`
.btn{
 top:15px;
 width:280px;
 height:74px;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 background-size:280px 74px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-image:url(../img/btn-purchase.png);
}
`

Need help on how to make it as pure css instead of making it as an image.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should share what you have tried when asking a question

this is not a code making site. we help you debug your pre-existing code.

but anyway, here is an example of what you want to achieve ( i guess you are interested in the css-styles of the button eg shadows, borders etc. )

the below example is just one way to do it. it all depends on your html structure

let me know if it works for you

```css
.button { 
text-align:center;
background:yellow;
display:inline-block;
border-radius:15px;
padding:15px 30px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #cec202;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #cec202;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #cec202;
position:relative;
margin-left:15px;
cursor:pointer;

}

.button h1,.button p { margin:0}
.button:after {
  background:#906200;
  position:absolute;
  width:calc(100% + 10px);
  height:calc(100% + 15px);
  top:0;
  content:"";
  left:-5px;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="button">
<h1>I am a button</h1>
<p>More text under the button</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Mihai T

Thank you for the help. Very new with coding and not aware of such requirements. Need to practice more.

Thanks so much

Comment: @ShaneNickman glad i could help. if this answer was usefull to you...please rate is as accepted

Answer (score -1):

you can place images on buttons and many other elements. this checkbox was created like this
 [Adding an image to submit button using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20904817/adding-an-image-to-submit-button-using-css)

**HTML**

`<input type="submit" id="search" name="submit" alt="search" value="" >`

**CSS**

```
input#search{
    background:url(../search-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}
```

See this for example http://codepen.io/jointmedias/pen/HqCJe  - **CSS 3 checkbox image replacement**

Comment: The question could be also how to create a rounded border, how to create an external shadow, how to create an inner shadow, how to ...

Comment: Agree with sir @vals

Comment: Thank you to all who responded. Just new with stack overflow.